# Make object return float value python

Tags: python, object, get

I can't think of anything similar in any other language but hopefully python can do something like this...

What I need is the following:

When referencing an object's value, i need the object to return a float. Eg:

```
    b = AnyObject(3, 4)
    print(b) #Should output 0.75
```

I have already tried the following:

```
 def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    return float(self.param1/self.param2)
```

but this does not work. When printing b like this, i only get the object's reference:

```
<(...) object at 0x10fa77e10>
```

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Look at implementing `__str__` and `__repr__`

Comment: Do you still need it to be an object of that type after the fact?

Comment: What documentation/blog/whatever told you to implement `__get__` here? Meanwhile, do you just want to control how this _prints_, or do you actually need to make it act like a float value wherever you use it (so, e.g., you can multiply it by an int and get a float back)?

Comment: @Edgar Aroutiounian:
thank you! this was, what i was looking for, simply couldn't find the correct method to override!

Comment: @adarnert:
I want to make it act like a float, whenever I use ist, but using __repr__ seems to work

Comment: @WhiteBr0wnie_24: No, using `__repr__` does _not_ make it act like a float anywhere, it just makes it _print out_ like a float. Again, what does `2 + b` or `b.hex()` or `abs(b)` do?

Comment: `print()` looks for `__str__`. Full stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing `<Fraction object at 0xdeadbeef>` because that's what the `__str__` method of the `object` class returns in your Python implementation: the class name and the address. To make `print` work, you need to override the `__str__` method with your own code to replace the method inherited from `object`. And while you're at it, you can make `float(obj)` work by implementing the `__float__` method.

```
from __future__ import division

class Fraction(object):

    def __init__(self, num, den):
        self.num, self.den = num, den

    # the built-in function float(obj) calls obj.__float__()
    def __float__(self):
        """float(self): Return a float approximating the fraction."""
        return self.num / self.den

    # Python 2.6/2.7/3.x print() function and Python 2 print statement
    # call str(obj), which calls obj.__str__()
    def __str__(self):
        """str(self): Return a string representing the fraction."""
        return str(float(self))
```

Comment: Aside:  Python already has a perfectly fine fraction type:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html  :-).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the division of integers is also an integer:

```
>>> 3 / 4
0
```

You need to give the object floats as arguments, or coerce integer arguments into floats before dividing:

```
>>> 3.0 / 4.0
0.75
>>> float(3) / float(4)
0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Reis: Thanks a lot for your answer, but this is absolutely not my issue. My issue was never that a wrong number was returned anywhere, but that referencing to the object gave me a object (as usually wanted) rather than a float (like i wanted it), but by defining the two methods:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(float(self.attr1/self.attr2))

def __str__(self):
    return str(float(self.attr1/self.attr2))
```

I got what I wanted (see the original posts comments!